# Android: Activity onResume

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, onresume

I have two activities, homework and closer.  I have a song playing in homework but when a button is pressed, the media player pauses and closer is opened.  In my onResume function for homework, I'm trying to start the media player again but no sound plays.  Can anybody help me out with this?

```
package com.cis.lab4;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Homework extends Activity {

    final MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    int media_length;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homework);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homework);
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try {
            afd = getAssets().openFd("rev.mp3");
            mediaplayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            mediaplayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaplayer.start();
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeworkContinue);
        final Intent openCloser = new Intent(this, EndActivity.class);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaplayer.pause();
                media_length = mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
                startActivity(openCloser);

            }

        });
    }

    public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onResume();
        mediaplayer.seekTo(media_length);
        mediaplayer.start();
    }


}
```

Comment: are you getting any kind of errors in the logs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try saving the media state in the `onPause()` method of the activity instead of instead of in the `onClick()`event. This guarantees that every time the `onResume()` will be called the `onPause()` will be called before that (except for the first time the activity runs, in which case the `onResume()` will be called after the `onStart()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try checking in the `onResume()` if mediaplayer is null.

if it is null then you will need to call `mediaPlayer.prepare()`.

perhaps put this code into it's own function:

```
try {
    afd = getAssets().openFd("rev.mp3");
    mediaplayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
    mediaplayer.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

that way you can call it in the `onResume()`/`onCreate()`.  In the `onResume()` try doing a null check. if it's null then call your new function to prepare the mediaPlayer.